# Can't install firebase tools in React

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install

I got this error when I going to install firebase using this. `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
I read the questions related to firebase install errors.  But a proper solution was not found.

npm version - 8.15.0

node version - v16.17.0

```
> PS E:\React\todo_list> npm install -g firebase-tools npm WARN
> deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
> npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4
> <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js
> environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or
> 4.3.1debug/issues/797) npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See
> https://v8.dev/blog/ma npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has
> been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> 
> changed 706 packages, and audited 707 packages in 17s
> 
> 39 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
> 
> 27 vulnerabilities (20 moderate, 7 high)
> 
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
> 
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:   npm audit
> fix --force
```

Comment: You have warnings, not an error. Have you tried using the command?

Comment: No, I did not try to fix the warning errors.